# Create user on non-booted Ubuntu

Tags: authentication, ubuntu

I was wondering if there were a way to create a user on an unbooted system (Ubuntu) ?
I have a HDD (Slave) which host a Ubuntu and I want to create a user on the system without booting on it.

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a trick : I booted on a live USB, ant then did a useradd to add the user as i wanted to.
Then I copied the lines generated in the /etc/shadow and /etc/passwd to the HDD and it were done.

Answer (score -1):

After you, Log into Ubuntu using your user name and password. Type "su root" and press "Enter."

Supply your root password to gain full system control privileges. Press "Enter" to confirm the action.

Create a new user account. Type "useradd -s /usr/sbin/nologin username" and press "Enter." Replace "username" with the name of the user you would like to create. This creates a new "No Login" account.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that, in your solution, the system has to be booted. I was asking how to do it on a **non-booted** system.